# Como passar um parâmetro para ser usado em outra pagina usando html

Tags: javascript, html

Bom estou criando uma bliblioteca de video e preciso passar o video correspondente a imagem clicada na pagina para outra pagina que recebera o video correspondente

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="preview">
      <a href="/web/video-play.html"><img src="video1.png"></a>
      <div class="time">00.20</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você está usando alguma linguagem de backend? Como você faz acesso ao seu banco de dados?

Comment: Você pode passar isso como parametro no PHP, do uma procurada em como usar parametros a partir da url no próprio SO PT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) primeiro vc vai passar suas variáveis para outra página por get normalmente

```
<a href="/web/video-play.php?v=67452"><img src="video1.png"></a>
```

na outra pagina vc vai fazer

```
<script>
    function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
    }
</script>
```

pode ser dentro da head e logo após vc pega as variáveis passadas assim

```
<script>
var video= getUrlVars()["v"];
alert(video);
</script>
```

em uma src:

```
<img src='' id='minhaimg'>
<script>
$("#minhaimg").attr("src", video);
</script>
```

obs: isso usando jquery

para video full javascript

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var source = document.createElement('source');

source.setAttribute('src',video);

video.appendChild(source);
video.play();
```

dai você só cria a tag vídeo sem source nenhum

Comment: bem na vdd o caminho pra pag é /web/video-play.html tinha colocado errado, mesmo assim funcionaria?

Comment: claro vc passa depois do nome do arquivo ?nomedavariavel=valordavariavel

Comment: nao esquece d marcar como concluído se deu certo

Comment: como eu faço pra usar o valor dessa variavel em uma src?

Comment: editado acima. so da uma olhada

Comment: tem alguma maneira de fazer com javascript, e funciona com src tag video?

Comment: acrescentado na edição com jaca script para tag video